# DirectX Definitions Missing?

Tags: c++, directx, mingw, directx-11

I've been trying to get DirectX 11 to compile on MinGW. So far the only problem I'm having is that the headers are giving me errors saying that certain DirectX related stuff isn't defined.

So far I linked the libraries with `-mwindows`, `-ld3d11`, `-d3dx11`, and `-ld3dx10`. All the headers and libraries are in the default folders for the compiler.

I also did this before including the DirectX headers (this is needed for MinGW):

```
#define __in
#define __out
#define __inout
#define __in_bcount(x)
#define __out_bcount(x)
#define __in_ecount(x)
#define __out_ecount(x)
#define __in_ecount_opt(x)
#define __out_ecount_opt(x)
#define __in_bcount_opt(x)
#define __out_bcount_opt(x)
#define __in_opt
#define __inout_opt
#define __out_opt
#define __out_ecount_part_opt(x,y)
#define __deref_out
#define __deref_out_opt
#define __RPC__deref_out

#include "stdint.h"

typedef uint8_t UINT8;
```

I'm going to assume I did everything correct, but I get errors such as `'ID3D11DeviceContext' was not declared in this scope` and `'pContext' was not declared in this scope`. I don't know why it's doing this. Did I miss a step?

Comment: You probably missed to include some D3D header file.

Comment: I found out `ID3D11DeviceContext` should have been defined in `d3d11.h`. I included it. I don't know why it's doing this.